# Can I sculpt a mesh with another mesh in Blender?

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

I do a lot of boolean operations on meshes during my design.
I was thinking about writing an add-on similar to Multi Tools, that would allow me to use actual meshes, not just (rectangles and polygons like in Multi Tools) to carve other meshes.
Here are some possible use cases:
- Add a mesh to the scene and set it as a Carve Tool in the properties window (on the right). The carve tool changes color in object mode to become red (all red).
- Move the carve tool towards another mesh. When the carve tool intersects the other mesh(es), they too becomes red. Validate the modification by pressing ENTER.
- Change the current operation using the spacebar between Union/Intersect/Difference.

Constraints:
1) The carving/sculpting operation preserves the modifier stack.
2) The carving tool should allow future reversals. One way to do this is as follow: the carving adds a Boolean modifier to the stack, hides the carving tool mesh (including rendering), renames it and parents it to the modified mesh.

Is there already such an add-on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Done!
The BoolTool Addon fulfills all the use cases presented above and more.
Youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vf2M1bxZYk0