# How can I cut this mesh into the object while it retains it's shape?

Tags: modeling, mesh, knife-tool

I've been modeling this Daihatsu Midget for a while now and I got to this part but I don't know how to "cut through and paste" these objects into the rear panel.

What I have:
[image]

What I would like to have:
[image]

So it can be part of the panel.

I tried knife project but that only cuts the outline of the objects and the rotation of object and the red panel is different so I can't just move it into the panel and merge the vertices.

Thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: Sorry about this late comment, but did you try the boolean (difference) modifier?  you can then "hide" the cutting object.

Comment: Hi, I tried it but as the cutting mesh is not exactly rotated as the mesh that needs to be cut it just partially works, but thanks anyway

Comment: You might want to consider including a reduced blend file (only the essentials to meet the <30MB requirement of [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/).  If I cannot figure it out, I can start a bounty as I have enough points to share.  Indeed knife project only does an outline, and only of manifold edges.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try out the (included) add-on Bool Tool as demonstrated [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7LpZKCjF7k) that will use one objects mesh, to cut another object, the solution to this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/104873/111042).

In the following I demonstrate using a sphere positioned into a cube.  The tool creates the additional required vertices in the sphere in the positions of the same vertices of the sphere and connects the edges to existing edges of the cube:

[image]

The wire sphere you see is a duplicate of the cutting/boolean-diff sphere.  The cutter is deleted/joined to the cut mesh and cannot be "changed" in the future.  I.e., the cut object mesh is permanently changed, so you might want to keep hidden copies of the original (cut and cutter) if you decide to change the sculpting later.

You can also investigate using a mesh as a sculpting tool, although that would also permanently change to sculpted object.